# MySQL output into CSV/Excel with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I've been learning a bit of PHP for a small school project. The project is almost done just that 1 thing is missing. I need a way to output something I searched into CSV / Excel.
I found a script which im using currently. It works beautifully I just can't figure out how to create a search form for it.

```
<?php
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "root"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "database";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "table"; //MySQL Table Name   
$filename = "search";         //File Name
//create MySQL connection 
$sql = "Select column1, column2 , ...  from $DB_TBLName";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
}   
?>
```

I got it to output all columns I wanted. I just can't figure out how I can create a search form for it..
Tried to adjust the code and parse a value to it with html forms - like that

```
    <form action="index.php" method="GET">
    Search : 
    <input type="text" name="query" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search!" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to add a where query to `$sql`.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `my_table`;
if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) 
{
     $sql .= 'WHERE `my_column` = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['query']) . '\'';
}
```

You also need to look into `mysqli_` instead of `mysql_` (`mysql` is deprecated) as that will allow you to use prepared statements. You should also use [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) and write to an actual file instead of printing. That will let you preserve newlines and tabs without needing to manage it yourself.

Comment: thank you for that already. I now changed the code a bit and created a form. Now it gives me an error : " Couldn't execute query:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE 'port 8'' at line 1
1064 "  The code now looks like that : http://pastebin.com/W1fcJjKy very much appreciate your help!